# Ruby: Ignore periods in directories when searching all directories for files?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I created a find script to search for text in files in all directories from which the script is ran.

```
print "Enter text to search: "
input = gets.chomp

search = Regexp.escape(input)

Dir.glob("**/*.*").each do |file|
        data = File.read(file)
        if data.match(search)
        puts "Text Found: " + __dir__ + "/" + file
 end
 end
```

It works but I get this error as the directory I am searching in contains directory names with periods..

```
find.rb:7:in `read': Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - cramws/cram_ws.egg-info (Errno::EISDIR)
    from find.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
    from find.rb:6:in `each'
    from find.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

How can I ingore these?

Comment: Try this `Dir.glob("**/*?.*")..`. This should skip hidden files.

Comment: @Stefan Ok.. I misunderstood then,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, you can add:

`next if File.directory?(file)`

at the beginning of your block.